# Accessible website with multiple homepages

Tags: accessibility, html, wcag

We're building a website, that people will be sent to from an email. There's multiple home pages, because there are different groups in the email list that the home pages correspond to. So to keep the site ADA, do we need to include links to all the home pages on the site, or since people are not intended to see all the home pages, is it okay to eliminate them from navigation?

Comment: Is it purely asthetics to exclude people from home pages not intended for them? What are the advantages of giving them access to the other pages and disadvantages or denying them, and vice verse? I'm not familiar with the ADA, but can't imagine it is dissimilar from our DDA and in that respect, denying access to content isn't an issue, it's making that content inaccessible,

Comment: The different home pages have different content that is specific to that group of people that get sent to it. So the intention is for people to only see one of the home pages, with it's tailored content. Since people aren't intended to see all the content I'm not sure if it's against ADA or not to make it inaccessible. My main issue is trying to interpret the "Multiple Ways" rule against this scenario https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/#navigation-mechanisms-mult-loc

Comment: I don't think it applies, you're not changing the navigation, your changing content.

Comment: Hmm...well we aren't using AJAX or something to switch out the content. Each homepage has a different url. Maybe that's the crux of the issue.

Comment: I understand, however your a home page is a home page. That said, you may want to consider content switching for analytics purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Is this really a home page, or a squeeze page?

A home page would be a centralized portal from which many scenarios originate.  It makes sense, if you have multiple home pages, to list them in some kind of navigation or, at very least, the site map.  Alternatively, if the homepages are close in structure, you could have a single home page, that shows some content conditionally based on the user's origin.  This does not need to be separately navigable.

A squeeze page by contrast is a step between a lead (originating in an off-site advertisement) and a conversion.  This meets the definition of a [process](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-mult-loc.html#key-terms) and should be exempt.

Comment: was going to say the same, although I call them *landing*. The only thing I would add is: there's only ONE homepage per site. Otherwise we'd be looking at different sites, or if within the site, landing or taxonomy pages/hubs. Other than that, +1 for a very good answer